# When selling your phone, what steps should be taken to make sure that all personal data has been removed?

Tags: security, samsung-galaxy-s-4, privacy

I am getting rid of my Samsung Galaxy S4 and want to know what steps I should take to make sure that private information has been deleted from the phone.  I have removed the SD card and cleared all of the gallery files as well as music.  What other steps can I take to make sure that the phone is as sterile as possible?

Comment: We have, on this stackexchange, found that Dropbox must be properly disengaged, otherwise a connected device will re-synch. See the answers to this [question](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/52462/i-did-a-factory-reset-to-sell-my-phone-and-my-photos-are-still-there-according).

Comment: See: [I have sold my phone on eBay. What should I do before I send it off?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/4623/16575) / [What's the most complete way to erase all the data from my phone so it cannot be recovered?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/422/16575) and check other [questions tagged `privacy`](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/privacy) for a start ;)

Comment: the guys tell you to overwrite  the storage, i don't know about android but I know about PCs and hard disks,  I've done data recovery with many tools available for anyone, free and commercial. and I can trace information back for like 5 years ago so I doubt that overwriting will work, so I won't even bother. one either knows how to do data recovery or he doesn't and if he does, chances are you're busted unless you physically destroy the  drive but then you won't be able to sell it

Comment: [How to make a complete factory reset, without anyone being able to retrieve my data?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/214496/218526)

Answer (score 20):

Remove the SD Card and SIM Card, and then do a Factory Reset.

If your device doesn't use full disk encryption, and you are worried about someone using advanced forensic tools to recover your data, you might want to overwrite the internal storage area with random data. You can do this by creating a file containing random data that fills up the entire free space. Once you've done that, do another factory reset.

If you've flashed and/or rooted your device, you would want to flash a stock ROM, and restore the default boot loader.

Comment: The tools needed to recover are hardly "advanced". If your device does not have full disk encryption, you really need to do a full wipe of all partitions of the internal storage except the bootloader, then reinstall stock 'ROM', but if you mess this up you could brick the device. Getting a professional you can trust to do this for you is going to cost a lot more than the device is worth, so honestly I would just recommend that privacy-conscious non-experts just destroy used devices rather than selling them... :-(

Comment: For example, this tool will recover **a lot** of data and all you need to know how to do is compile for Linux/ARM and root the device: http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec

Answer (score 6):

Make sure you've deregistered your phone from e.g. Google (especially Play), Facebook, Dropbox etc.

Encrypt the phone, optionally create a file full of random data that fills up all available disk space<sup>1</sup>, then factory reset. Repeat as many times as you like.

<sup>1</sup> `dd if=/dev/urandom of=random.txt bs=1G count=2`, replacing `1G` with however much space is left ([credit](http://linuxcommando.blogspot.co.uk/2008/06/create-file-of-given-size-with-random.html))

Comment: I doubt this suffices; personal information might be stored not just in free (deleted) space but also in files that don't get properly deleted.

Comment: Would filling up disk space with random data like that even work? Doesn't the type of memory used in phones typically use wear leveling? (E.g. Similar to an SSD?) So even if the disk is full there might still be sectors that haven't been overwritten.

Comment: @Ajedi32 I assume that (especially with multiple write cycles) most data would be overwritten. Without specialist tools it's presumably impossible to force all sectors to be written to and erased.

Comment: @JoshHolland  Is it possible to deregister a device from Google (especially Play) anymore?  If so, how?

Comment: @RockPaperLizard I thought it was under settings on the web interface, but apparently you can't.

Comment: @JoshHolland I believe Google used to allow you to deregister a device, but for some reason, they removed that functionality.  :(

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to flash a factory image, maybe a more daunting task if you aren't familiar with it. However, check out sammobile.com for images and instructions, or YouTube of course.

In theory, with Android, a factory reset can tend to leave data behind: [Ars article](http://arstechnica.com/security/2015/05/flawed-android-factory-reset-leaves-crypto-and-login-keys-ripe-for-picking/)

With a system image, it effectively rewrites all partitions on the device, leaving it clean.